# How do I change the email address used in my Sitecore Community profiles?

Tags: community

I need to change the email address I use to log into SDN, SPN, http://support.sitecore.net, dev.sitecore.net, and the rest of the community sites.

How do I do this?

Comment: I asked this user to create this question because it is an extremely common one. It needs to be edited.

Comment: I would say this is a fair question. Lot of people face this issue.

Comment: Yup, I would definitely vote to allow this question. It is specific, answerable, and of wide interest to our community. The point of this site was that it was not solely focused on developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that yourself. Contact one of the administrators (e.g. Mark van Aalst) to get you through that process.

Comment: thanks. where can I get the contact of the administrators?

Comment: On the community site itself (if you can still login). Or on twitter, ...

Comment: If you log into SPN (http://spn.sitecore.net/), it shows "My Sitecore Contact" in the upper right. If you read out to this individual, they will be able to assist you with your request.